# Why to not leave data in HDFS,

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, hdfs, google-cloud-storage

Last day while I was following my courses on GCP in coursera, they mentioned and they insisted that we should not leave the data in HDFS, but instead after finishing the job, we should copy it and persist in cloud storage, and each time we want to launch a job, we should put the data again in HDFS and repeat the loop,
so my questions are the following:

1. Do we lose our data in HDFS if we turn off the hadoop cluster?
2. Why we should not leave the data in HDFS?
3. Price issues?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The pros and cons of Cloud Storage vs. HDFS](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/hdfs-vs-cloud-storage-pros-cons-and-migration-tips)

**Moving to Cloud Storage**

**1. The cons:**

a. Cloud Storage may increase I/O variance.

b. Cloud Storage does not support file appends or truncates.

c. Cloud Storage is not POSIX-compliant.

d. Cloud Storage may not expose all file system information.

e. Cloud storage may have greater request latency.

**2. The pros:**

a. Lower costs.

b. Separation from compute and storage.

c. Interoperability.

d. HDFS compatibility with equivalent (or better) performance.

e. High data availability.

f. No storage management overhead.

g. Quick startup.

h. Google IAM security.

i. Global consistency.